# Edge.JS fails in the Testing Environment without any error

Tags: c#, edgejs

I built an application using Edge.JS. It works fine in the dev environment but fails in the testing environment (Windows Server 2012 R2). No error or an exception is raised and the process simply gets killed

It fails at this line `Edge.Func(SomeScript);`

I have two questions mainly:

Is there a place where I can look for the errors?
Does Edge.JS have any dependencies other than the ones mentioned in the github site?

Any help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Edge.JS has a dependency on vcruntime.dll. I found it out after running [ProcessMonitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) tool. Additionally you can also try and open edge_nativeclr.node in [dependencywaler](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) tool. It will clearly show the dependencies of the edgeJs. To fix it I had to install [Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=48145) in the Testing machine.